# Issue with update in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose, crud

I have wrote a simple Update function. Its working fine for some minutes and then again its not working. Where I am going wrong? Please help me. I use PUT as my method.

**code**

```
accept = (req, res) => {
    this._model.update({
        user: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.uid)
    }, {
        $set: {
            status: 'active'
        }
    }, (err, obj) => {
        if (err || !obj) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.send(obj);
        }
    });
}
```

**Model**

```
  {
   "_id":"5d3189a00789e24a23438a0d",
   "status":"pending",
    "user":ObjectId("5d3189a00789e24a23438a0d"),
   "code":"CT-123-345-234-233-423344",
   "created_Date":"2019-07-19T09:13:04.297Z",
   "updated_Date":"2019-07-19T09:13:04.297Z",
   "__v":0
  }
```

**Request**

```
api.abc.com/api/accept/5d3189a00789e24a23438a0d
```

Sometime it is returing values and sometime null.

Comment: The null you were getting is "err" variable, it returned it since it matched with !obj.
Are you sure u are sending correct uid, console log it? 
Tip: You don't new "new" on the mongoose.Types.ObjectId

Comment: Its going to `else` part @noitse

Comment: By all the coding logic, that makes no sense, if you check your if statement, it says if there is an error, or no obj (! will consider null, undefined as true) it will enter the first block. There no logic it went to else and sent obj as null.

Comment: I issue is it is always going to else block sometime its returning values and other times as `null`

Comment: It looks like your the user object id is stored as a string in the collection `"user":"ObjectId(5d3189a00789e24a23438a0d)"` its should be of objectId type.

Comment: It is `user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }` I have edited the schema take a look

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to ensure the model is tied to a connection. This could be an issue of connection to the database.

```
const config = require('./config');
console.log('config.database.url', config.database.url);

return mongoose.createConnection(config.database.url, {
    useMongoClient: true
})
.then((connection) => {
    // associate model with connection
    User = connection.model('User', UserSchema);

    const user = new User({
        email: 'someuser@somedomain.com',
        password: 'xxxxx'
    });

    const prom = user.update();

    // Displays: 'promise: Promise { <pending> }'
    console.log('promise:', prom);

    return prom
    .then((result) => {
        // Don't see this output
        console.log('result:', result);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        // Don't see this output either
        console.log('error:', error);
    });
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use promise or async/await, try this

```
accept = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await this._model.update({
      user: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.uid)
    }, {
        $set: {
          status: 'active'
        }
      });
    return res.send(result);
  } catch (e) {
    return res.send(e);
  }
};
```

Comment: facing same issue. First time i got response with success code and next time I am getting null with the success code. I didn't go to `catch`

Comment: are you updating the same status, in next call? @Chris